# SSRS: Nested IIF expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that has a column for Quarter based on the Month for a specific client.

For example: It Client-Texas has a `Fields!PayoutPeriodStart_Disp.Value="MAR"` then Quarter should be:

Quarter 1 covers months of Mar, Apr, May
Quarter 2 covers months of Jun, Jul, Aug
Quarter 3 covers months of Sep, Oct, Nov
Quarter 4 covers months of Dec, Jan, Feb

If the `Fields!PayoutPeriodStart_Disp.Value<>"MAR"` then the quarter should be

Quarter 1 covers months of Jan, Feb, Mar
Quarter 2 covers months of Apr, May, Jun
Quarter 3 covers months of Jul, Aug, Sep
Quarter 4 covers months of Oct, Nov, Dec

Bu I am having issues with my expression `=IIF(Fields!PayoutPeriodStart_Disp.Value="Mar",
    IIF(Fields!Month.Value="3" OR Fields!Month.Value="4" OR Fields!Month.Value="5","Quarter 1",
        IIF(Fields!Month.Value="6" OR Fields!Month.Value="7" OR Fields!Month.Value="8","Quarter 2",
            IIF(Fields!Month.Value="9" OR Fields!Month.Value="10" OR Fields!Month.Value="11","Quarter 3",
                IIF(Fields!Month.Value="12" OR Fields!Month.Value="1" OR Fields!Month.Value="2","Quarter 4"
    ,"")))),IIF(Fields!Month.Value="1" OR Fields!Month.Value="2" OR Fields!Month.Value="3","Quarter 1",
        IIF(Fields!Month.Value="4" OR Fields!Month.Value="5" OR Fields!Month.Value="6","Quarter 2",
            IIF(Fields!Month.Value="7" OR Fields!Month.Value="8" OR Fields!Month.Value="9","Quarter 3",
                IIF(Fields!Month.Value="10" OR Fields!Month.Value="11" OR Fields!Month.Value="12","Quarter 4"
    ,"")))))`

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a little more context around what the issues are.  For instance, what is the expected value in this case (i.e. what is PayoutPeriodStart_Disp.Value).  Your base expression looks good (and I validated the syntax on a test box), so just trying to understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: I need to change the Quarter label to Quarter 1, Quarter 2, Quarter 3, Quarter 4 based on the value of Payout value start display if MAR then the about Quarter label will display for whatever month.

Comment: Looks like the value of Fields!Month is a string with something like "Oct" not the number value of the month Is that true?. Also, two `switch` statements would probably be easier to read than the nested IIFs

Comment: I already figured it out. thanks.